# Should we burninate the [close] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag wiki for [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) states:

> In general, close is the action performed to terminate a portion of a
>   program or the complete program. If a file has changed since it was
>   opened and the program is closed, any changes done to the open file
>   may be lost. If the program closes without performing the close
>   action, this is usually referred to as a crash.
>
> In general, close is the action performed to terminate a portion of a
>   program or the complete program. If a file has changed since it was
>   opened and the program is closed, any changes done to the open file
>   may be lost. If the program closes without performing the close
>   action, this is usually referred to as a crash.
>
> Tip: Pressing the keyboard shortcut key Alt + F4 in Windows closes an
>   open program and if the program has any open windows or tabs pressing
>   Ctrl + F4 or Ctrl + W closes the current open window or tab.
>
> When referring to a button or a feature in a GUI operating system, the
>   close box or close button allows a user to terminate a window within a
>   program or the complete program.
>
> For example, In Microsoft Windows operating systems and other
>   operating systems and software programs, the close button with a "X"
>   is located in the top right corner of the window. If there are
>   multiple windows opened within the program, the "X" at the top right
>   corner closes the program and the bottom "X" closes the window but
>   keeps the program open. In the picture below, is an example of the
>   close button.

The tag wiki refers to closing programs. However, questions include closing programs, closing windows, and closing files. Seems ambiguous to me. What do you guys think?

Comment: No one can be specialized in closing all kinds of programs. So, please, let's burninate this tag.

Comment: Not to mention that, in programming, the term 'close' is probably used more frequently to refer to releasing resources like handles, file pointers, sockets, etc. than to termination of the program (which is usually called 'termination' or 'exiting.') In C, for example, `close()` closes a file handle, while `exit()` terminates the program. I say burn it.

Comment: 250 ... there is another one! It _could_ be a context tag but this one does not seem to be useful in that regard.

Comment: It has been my lifelong dream to one day become a great *close* consultant. If you destroy this tag I will have one less reason to live.

Comment: Do note that `close` is a standard POSIX function, which would make it a perfectly valid tag in that context. Certainly a cleanup is warranted, most questions with this tag are mistagged or completely inappropriate. But the fact that something has a generic name does not make it an invalid tag.

Comment: @CodyGray I suggest you write an answer to propose that we keep the tag then.

Comment: @CodyGray: I suspect many languages/API have a `close` function/method, however experts in one language/API are not necessarily experts in all others. Should not question on the POSIX `close` benefit from a more specific tag? Or are you expecting a tag combination (posix + close)?

Comment: Definitely a combination of tags, as would be required for just about any tag using the name of a function or library. They don't indicate a language.

Comment: Maybe we should have `posix-close` tag? `close` on its own seems vague, and would probably be misused.

Comment: As was mentioned above, remove the [close] tag and replace it with a context oriented one like [posix-close] or [file-close]. Super generic words without any context only cause confusion.

Comment: Aaaah I wish we could still have fun with the titles. "[close] enough"

Comment: The silly titles are great.  But for the brief time that the title is visible to everyone unfamiliar with this process, it needs to sound like a discussion rather than a call to action.

Comment: @davidism I would prefer that we close some of these questions first.

Comment: @AndrasDeak http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316947/keep-the-love-of-puns-burninating-in-our-hearts

Comment: @LuisMasuelli: See [my question on the subject](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316947/keep-the-love-of-puns-burninating-in-our-hearts) that ivan_pozdeev already linked. If you can come up with a pun that's extremely clear, that might be suitable... but editing the title while it's featured isn't generally necessary, except at times for clarity.

Comment: I would agree that the close tag probably is too vague and really context dependent. There are usually better words like the examples terminate and release.

Comment: I think terminate exit and release all fall into the same trap. They mean different things to different people and are too context-specific to be useful. I only monitor for tags that interest me - in my case Delphi and Dephi-xe - which are broad enough to be useful. The title of the question should introduce the specifics, like close, etc. I think remove it (never heard of burninate before...)

Comment: Delphi-XE I love you

Answer (score 5):

Tag has been burninated! Thanks to the community at large.

---

## Progress

You can help out by reviewing the questions and answers in these tags and:

- flag or close questions that are duplicate/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion based;
- filter on these tags in the Close Vote Queue and review;
- vote on the questions and its answers;
- delete vote the question or answer(s) if there is nothing of value;
- editing to add value (re-tag), or;
- flag obsolete comments

Here are some easy links to get you started:

[close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close)

- <strike>[Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclose%5D+closed%3Ano) 14</strike>
- <strike>[Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclose%5D+closed%3Ayes) 24</strike>
- <strike>[No answers](http://stackoverflow.com%3C/strike%3E/search?q=%5Bclose%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano) 14</strike>
- [No accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bclose%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano) 14

[Review in the Close vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close?filter-tags=close)

Remember that we don't want to destroy value so let salvaging a post be your first priority!

If you have specific questions feel free to drop in the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room or leave a comment under this post.

Answer (score 1):

While [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) is ambiguous, [application-shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-shutdown) is a common problem and one can an expert in it (across many platforms).  There are common problems from one language to another.

While it is true that not all [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) tagged questions should be tagged [application-shutdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application-shutdown), removing the [close](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/close) without replacing it on the thousands(?) of cases where it is talking about a useful concept that one can have expertise in is harming the site.

If the name of the tag is poor and it leads to the wrong use, rename the tag, don't delete it.  If many posts need to be untagged for this to work, do the untagging.

Comment: That tag is garbage, too. It doesn't represent any specific topic that someone might be an expert in. Observe how it's being used for everything from batch files, to C programs, to ASP.Net web apps, Android, iOS, etc.

Comment: @AndrewMedico That concept spans languages, so?

Comment: So? It doesn't work as a standalone tag. Questions and answers are going to be highly language-specific.

Comment: @AndrewMedico The only tags that usually work as a standalone tag on stack overflow itself are basically language tags (as reflected by the rule that you should include a language tag in basically every post).  And in this case, there are general application shutdown concerns that are ridiculously cross-language (what happens to file handles etc) compared to most other tags.  Unless your opinion is that every tag should always be prefixed with the language it occurs in?  That seems redundant.