# Why was my duplicate question deleted?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I asked a question a long time ago shown here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214178/how-do-i-hide-the-x-so-that-it-doesnt-appear-in-the-toolbar

[image]

Today I noticed in my reputation tab today that I had lost reputation.

When investigating further I noticed my question has been deleted. I can only presume because it is a duplicate?

Trying to investigate whether duplicates should be deleted I found [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) `meta.Stackexchange` post which states:

> **Should duplicates be deleted?**
>
> In general, no: most duplicates stay
> around. Having multiple copies of the same question with different
> wording is useful as search fodder, because people looking for an
> answer may use different wording too.
>
> Duplicates that are word-for-word copies or that are so poorly written
> that they are not useful may be deleted by users with sufficient
> privilege.

but I don' t think my question meets the criteria for deleting.

So why was my question deleted?

Comment: I don't think it should be deleted, voted to reopen.

Comment: @HansPassant The different phrasing "How do I hide the X" adds "SEO value". [No other other question](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22How+do+I+hide+the+X%22) has this.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: The face that 50% of the question's title is unique on SO isn't a good reason to keep a question around, if that's the only thing the question has going for it. People generally search for something like "Close button", which has plenty of good results.

Comment: @Cerbrus I've often heard it phrased as "x" by non-tech people at least in Dutch, so this is why I used only that part. Is it a *good enough* reason to keep it? *shrug* maybe, maybe not ...

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211518/remove-closex-button-from-wpf-window) (not yet closed as a dupe because it was mistagged) already exists that uses the "x" phrasing. And it's a better question to boot.

Comment: @CodyGray and that question has 3 upvotes, 7500 views and everyone is happy to keep that question around besides it being essentially the same as mine.. Just another day on SO I suppose

Comment: Uh, it is a lot older. More time to get votes and views. Don't take this so personally.

Comment: this particular question is pretty useless and shows extremely low effort on the OP part, I can not think of any definition that would show that it is a net positive to the site in anyway. It is a screen shot with a *do my research, read the docs and write my code for me* disguised as a question, why are we even talking about this like it is some arcane bit of knowledge from the beginning of the site? It is just part of the ["Every question is sacred!](https://youtu.be/fUspLVStPbk?t=53s) movement.

Comment: @user1 - if you had done a minimum amount of your own research and found that other question you are complaining about you would not have asked the one you are complaining about getting closed and deleted, and is probably about to get deleted again. It is a poorer question and just adds noise to the main site, and now noise to meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the question was deleted isn't because it was a duplicate. We generally don't like deleting duplicates.

The reason it was deleted is because **[there's an ongoing effort to burninate the *close* tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308117/871050)**.

Having received relatively little votes and view over the past year, the folks decided there's no need to keep it around. If you think differently, please edit the question to remove the tag (and make the necessary generalizations to the question so that the tag isn't needed anymore), then flag the question to get it undeleted.

Comment: Huh? You nuke content just to burninate a tag? This is nonsense. _Just remove the tag!_

Comment: There's a whole process behind burnination, it's not as simple as just removing the tags or just deleting everything. Every question is looked at individually and acted upon differently.

Comment: Then let's improve that process. If a question is a duplicate, then retag it to have the same tags as the target. This is a small inconvenience for the people doing the cleanup, and it preserves the content instead of destroying it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: From the point of view of the question under discussion, the result is precisely that y'all "just deleted everything". I don't think that should be within the scope of tag burnination whatsoever. Let's review that process.

Comment: Did the question have only the one tag?

Comment: You have gone beyond the already aggressive stance in the burniation steps: It states "A moderator will ping a CM to delete any closed, downvoted questions in the tag and remove it from the system entirely. This assumes the tag wasn't already removed during review in Step #4."  -- unless you are reading that as "closed OR downvoted" and not "closed AND downvoted".  A closed question is merely one that should not be answered, not one that should be deleted. A closed *and* downvoted question is maybe something that should be considered. But deleting just because it happens to have 1 bad tag?

Comment: Wow, great, burnination is even better than I thought!

Comment: The process has nuking content at step 6, *after* retagging at step 4.  Why was step 6 content-nuking done before retagging?  Or am I missing something from those steps?

Comment: I want to light my fireplace, but I don't feel like getting up from the couch. If I light my carpet on fire, it will eventually light my fireplace, too.

Comment: The SOCVR chat room is involved again.  We've been hearing a lot from that room lately, never anything positive it seems.  They are making up their own "process" now?  And anybody that disagrees about that tag burnination must report to that room??   Isn't that rather bizarre?.  High time perhaps to review the usefulness of that room.

Comment: @HansPassant Note that the process from SOCVR is [documented](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md) and was written in conjunction with guidance from mods and Shog9 himself. There's also nothing in there for deleting questions with a positive score.

Comment: @HansPassant I just looked at their process and I don't see the reason for the "review of the usefullness of the room"? Nor do I see anything bizarre in there.

Comment: Since when is github the place where consensus is hammered out?  Am I supposed to submit a pull request?  If nobody sees anything bizarre with that then I must have teleported to a site that isn't called meta.  Read the comments **here**, people do question the process.

Comment: @HansPassant GitHub is just a place to keep the text and it renders Markdown. The actual process (as mentioned in the gist) is from a [meta answer from Shog](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124) and it's only mildly tailored for the room. Feel free to start a meta post about the room though, I'm pretty sure everyone in there would welcome the opportunity to talk openly.

Comment: Am I missing something here, @DavidG? Why not just put it in a meta [meta-tag:faq-proposed] post, wiki up an answer, and let folks edit it there? I'd planned to do this eventually anyway, once we'd had a bit more experience with the process to know if it was worth doing, but if y'all are needing more legroom right now then go for it.

Comment: @Shog9 I think the room owners may have a better answer, but I think it's probably just because all the room info was already in that Github repo so that's where they put it to work on it, and it stuck. I'd be willing to bet they would love it to be a proper meta [tag:faq-proposed] hopefully eventually moving into a bonafide [tag:faq].

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for sharing your observation and voicing your concerns. I'll do my best to address those in both our room guidance, the burnination process and culture within our room as well as here on meta.  We can use some feedback from users that are not involved in our room but have plenty of mileage on both Stack Overflow and Meta. Much appreciated, keep it coming.

Answer (score 12):

I was about to cast a moderator vote to restore it, but folks seem to have beaten me to it :)

Duplicate questions are fine *and very helpful* to have around as long as the collection as a whole:

- Points to the *best* question with the *best* canonical answers
- Doesn't overly-duplicate the many unique ways that the same question could be searched for and asked. 12 "how do I hide the button" titles aren't nearly as helpful as a dozen asked in the variety of ways people might try searching
- Is a quality collection (each is likely to help on their own, and by linking people to the canonical).

There's no reason to delete duplicates that fall well into this criteria, and your question appears to be very much in line with it.

Don't get me wrong, there's no good reason to keep a dozen of the same things expressed in essentially the same way around - that doesn't do anything to help us cover the breadth of ways folks search. But that's not the case here, that I can tell.

Comment: Didn't take it long to receive a delete vote again though...

Comment: It's a 10-month old question with _56_ views. That's a whopping five and a half views per month. (Some of them from this meta post, no doubt). The title uses a single letter to describe an button, which isn't particularly search-engine-friendly. I wouldn't be surprised if the majority of people looking for a question like this would search for something like "Close button" instead of "X".

Comment: That said, [_"disable X on wpf window"_](https://www.google.nl/webhp?q=disable+X+on+wpf+window) already links to one of the [better Q/A pairs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window) out there

Comment: It's been deleted again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply clarifying this. Personally I thought the different wording of the same issue would be of benefit to SO as not everyone thinks the same. But it seems people are adamant to delete it so I guess I'll just let it lie

Comment: `Duplicate questions are fine and very helpful to have around as long as the collection as a whole:`  That's just not true.  *Some* duplicates are very helpful, in the fairly rare instances where they provide a very real window to the canonical.  There are posts that are going to be found when the canonical, or other duplicates, wouldn't be, but *that's not true of most duplicates*.  The *vast* majority of duplicates aren't useful.

Comment: Tim, seems like that post was deleted as part of the [tag:closed] tag cleanup. Having gained little votes and views over the last year or so, it was deleted.

Comment: @Servy inb4 yet another nullpointerexception duplicate