# When should I (we?) Vote to delete a dupe-closed question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete

This is regarding casting delete votes on dupe-closed question.

- I had read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled) in meta SE.
- I also had read [that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318594/2173917) in MSE.

Still, I fail to understand why three other users promptly VTD for [this duplicate (closed) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38696728/2173917).

I'm not asking to re-open, just curious about the reason why it needs to be deleted. As my understanding, I would not have voted for deletion. Did I miss something?

*P.S- For answering part, it was closed after it was answered.*

Comment: Dunno. The questioner added a sentence with an expletive after the question was closed as a dupe. It may have been enough to convince voters that the question would be better off deleted.

Comment: Well it doesn't look like it adds anything new to SO so we don't need to keep it.

Comment: @Nathan, we usually do not apply that logic to duplicates -- the consensus if that the more "paths" there are to a canonical Q/A pair, the better.

Comment: @NathanOliver isn't that the thing about dupes? They do not _add_ anything _new_ except the different wordings (for the same problem) which makes them easier to search. That , directly or indirectly, reduces the future dupe-questions.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Yes it has to make it easier to find.  Not sure about you guys but *In C, printf can request its demand to its parameter* does not help me find *What happens when I use the wrong format specifier*.  I vote to delete dupes that are poorly recieved and would have been easily googleable.

Comment: @NathanOliver Correct, maybe that needs _improvement_, not _deletion_, don't you agree?

Comment: @SouravGhosh If you feel you feel you can improve it go ahead.  As is though I see no reason to keep it.

Comment: @NathanOliver I completely respect your view, though, I beg to differ. I've tried an improvement. Let's see.

Comment: There is a practical upper limit on the number of duplicate questions about the exact same problem.  And it is not that high, Google's Panda algorithm punishes web sites that add content that is nothing more than link traps to old content.  When Google stops ranking SO content then we might as well quit.  You already knew this question was answered before, just don't post yet another answer.  It is bad enough that questioners treat SO as a personal helpdesk, when answerers encourage that behavior then we might as well quit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Duplicates shouldn't be deleted *when they provide a useful window into the canonical*. They're worth keeping around when they approach the same problem in a very different way, use radically different terminology, already have lots of inbound links to them or other google juice making them likely to attract traffic, or any other factor making them likely to attract traffic from users that wouldn't otherwise be able to find the canonical or another duplicate.

Quite simply, the vast majority of duplicate posts don't meet that criteria, at least for common duplicates.  They tend to use similar wording, don't have lots of sustained incoming traffic, etc.  They're just adding more noise for people to sort through or adding additional layers of indirection for people searching for the answer to this question *without helping people find a solution that wouldn't otherwise*.